# SQL query for limiting records

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have following SQL query in Data Flow, Control flow of SSIS package and I want to limit records by cutting off point, and that cut off point is current day/date from system. So, it should only display past records, not including todays. So, I think I need to use the specific field (which is date field - in the query its called 'FinalCloseDate' and compare with current system date and tell it to only to pull the records (perhaps < todays date) that happened before today or current system day.

Comment: You really should consider using aliases in your queries. You could reduce the amount of text by about 50% or more in this query. The real challenge is we have no idea what you are trying to do here. If you want rows that are older than today it is probably simply FinalCloseDate < convert(date, getdate())

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
AND dbo.Producthit.FinalCloseDate < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

to your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: NULLs will not be included, because NULLs would produce an unknown for that expression. You are left joining to that table, so you need to think about what that means.

Comment: I would make it a stored procedure and pass a parameter.  You can call stored procedures from SSIS and set their values from config, from script or from elsewhere.